# How to use jQuery Form Plugin with Rails js.erb template?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am using the jQuery Form Plugin with my Rails app. I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/comments" id="comment_form" method="post">
  <textarea cols="60" id="comment_comment" name="comment[comment]" rows="3"></textarea>
  <input id="comment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add comment" />
</form>
```

My application.js file has:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#comment_form").ajaxForm();
});
```

My Comments controller is like this:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

  respond_to do |wants|
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Added comment.'
      wants.js
    end
  end
end
```

And I have some jquery code in /views/comments/create.js.erb like:

```
$("#comment_form).hide();
```

and some other stuff.

My problem is the jQuery code inside create.js.erb never happens (i.e. the form doesn't get hidden). If I use this in application.js instead (thanks to Railscast for this code)

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#comment_form").submitWithAjax();
});
```

it all works fine. All the code in create.js.erb works great! I'd rather use the jQuery Form plugin, but I don't understand how to make create.js.erb code run. If do something like:

```
$("#comment_form").ajaxForm({success: function(){$("comment_form").hide()}});
```

then that jQuery code works. But I need to run the erb template (because I do things like render a partial inside).

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. While watching this screencast http://blog.edgecase.com/2009/6/15/ajax-file-uploads-made-easy-screencast - I noticed he added dataType: 'script'
So, instead of

```
$("#comment_form").ajaxForm();
```

I needed

```
$("#comment_form").ajaxForm({dataType: 'script'});
```

Works! And it's right there in the jQuery Form docs - "if dataType == 'script' the server response is evaluated in the global context"